# Timeout popup on icefaces 3.3.0

Tags: session, popup, timeout, icefaces

I'm using icefaces 3.3.0 with jsf 2 
I'm not very familiar with this, 
I'm trying to implement session timeout 
I'm redirected to the login page while timeout but not getting the popup that says : 
user session expired....
I already did this on the web.xml but it doesn't work :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.icefaces.disableDefaultErrorPopups</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add user session expired message value in "bridge-messages.properties" and this should be copied in server config folder.